# Does UIImageView Animation Run When Not Onscreen

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiimageview, background-process

In my app I use several UIImageViews for animating images. For these UIImageViews I call `startAnimating` and have the animation loop indefinitely. My app contains many different views and many times these UIImageViews are not on screen. Additionally my app runs while in the background. My question is, if for these UIImageViews I never call `stopAnimating` will the views continue to animate and consume processing power even when the UIImageViews are offscreen (i.e. either their superview is offscreen/hidden or the app is in the background)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I am not sure but I did find this in the apple documents

> Hiding Views
>
> To hide a view visually, you can either set its hidden property to YES
>   or change its alpha property to 0.0. A hidden view does not receive
>   touch events from the system. However, **hidden views do participate in
>   autoresizing and other layout operations associated with the view
>   hierarchy**. Thus, hiding a view is often a convenient alternative to
>   removing views from your view hierarchy, especially if you plan to
>   show the views again at some point soon.

I read through the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html) but could not really find anything to guarantee a solid answer. I remember through the online Standford courses I watch awhile back that hidden views are not drawn at all to preserve processing power. But are tracked (as explained above). That being said I would generally think Apple handles this in an efficient way but do not know for sure.

If you want a more definite answer you could just animate a bunch of views and track them with instruments to see how much they are consuming.